# How do I search for a phrase using search logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic

Imagine case scenario, you have a list of recipes that have ingredients as a text.

You want to see how many recipes contain "sesame oil".

The problem with default searchlogic searching using Recipe.ingredients_like("sesame oil") is that any recipe with sesame AND oil would come up, when I'm searching for "sesame oil" which is a problem when the recipe may contain things like "sesame seeds" + "corn oil"

Comment: You might also be interested in [Search by attribute_like_any using multiple words in one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639818/search-by-attribute-like-any-using-multiple-words-in-one-field-searchlogic) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return Recipes that contain `sesame oil` (two words separated by a space)

```
Recipe.ingredients_like("sesame oil")
#=> SELECT * FROM `recipes` WHERE (recipes.ingredients LIKE '%sesame oil%')
```

This will return Recipes that contain `sesame` **or** `oil` (any one of these words)

```
Recipe.ingredients_like_any("sesame", "oil")
#=> SELECT * FROM `recipes` WHERE (recipes.ingredients LIKE '%sesame%' OR recipes.ingredients LIKE '%oil%')
```

This will return Recipes that contain `sesame` **and** `oil` (both words in any order)

```
Recipe.ingredients_like_all("sesame", "oil")
#=> SELECT * FROM `recipes` WHERE (recipes.ingredients LIKE '%sesame%' AND recipes.ingredients LIKE '%oil%')
```