# search by attribute_like_any using multiple words in one field [searchlogic]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

My form

```
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name_like_any %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
@search = Product.search
@search.name_like_any(params[:search][:name_like_any].split(/\s+/))
@products = search.all
```

This returns the correct result, but now my form shows the name as `["foo", "bar"]` instead of what the user input (`"foo bar"`).

What's the elegant way to handle this?

Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Well, I found out the hard way first, then by asking another question, I inadvertently found a better answer to my original question. Here's the [secondary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648098/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-named-scope-rails).

### Model

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope_procedure :keywords, lambda { |query|
    name_like_any(query.split(/\s+/))
  }
end
```

### Controller

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:search])
    @products = @search.all
  end
end
```

### Views

```
# app/views/products/index.html.erb
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :keywords, "Quick Search" %>
  <%= f.input :keywords %>
  <%= f.submit, "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

---

## Stay tuned...

I'm having difficulty rallying up some of the more hard-to-answer questions for Searchlogic 2.x, but because tasks aren't always so straightforward, other questions tend to surface. Here's one I hope to answer that's not covered here.

[How to sanitize form params for use with Searchlogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653474/how-to-sanitize-form-params-for-use-with-searchlogic-rails)